# how to shut down a machine in 32 bit protected mode

Tags: assembly, kernel

I have been researching a method to shutdown computer without switching to 16 bit real mode. I cannot call BIOS functions in 32 bits protected mode. Although I have been looking for information about that for almost one week, I haven't been able to find any document or source code which works correctly. Because I am very new to low level programming, I doubt that it is not possible to shutdown a computer without switching to real mode. Is it? Thank you.

Comment: Computers run operating systems.  Operating systems support shutdown.  There's very little point in making this complicated, it is not like it is going to get much use :)

Comment: Okay. Since computers run operating systems, there is no need to learn anything.

Comment: Learn how to program the operating system.  A good skill to learn.  Hacking 16-bit code is not a skill, it became irrelevant 20 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the Advanced Configuration and Power Interface -- **ACPI** -- for this. ACPI is a large and complex set of structures and interfaces dealing with things such as power states, battery power, shutdown, power saving for devices, and much much more. If you are developing an operating system, you'll have to write a driver to set up ACPI and its tables so you can shut the computer down cleanly.

I'm not sure how to work with ACPI directly under Linux, and I'm nearly positive that Windows wouldn't even allow you to do anything directly with ACPI.

http://uefi.org/specifications Here are links to the specifications for ACPI as maintained by the UEFI Forum. Good luck, and godspeed.

Comment: Thank you. I already found some information about ACPI but I could not make it work. I need a tutorial for beginners or an explanatory source code.

Comment: Well, simply `outw(0xB004, 0x00002000)` shutdowns the machine while `outb(0x64, 0xFE)` restarts it. Thank you.

Comment: Fair warning, the magic outw(0xB004, 0x2000) shutdown **only** works in qemu and bochs. I'm fairly certain it doesn't work in VirtualBox or VMWare, and I am positive that no physical chipset supports it.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I tested it on bochs. Do you mean that outw(0xB004, 0x2000) will not work on real machine?